# Differences among meta-data, catalog, data dictionary, and schema

Tags: database-theory, databases

What is the exact meaning of  these terms? Very confusing. Most of the articles uses these terms interchangeably.

Comment: What research?  Wikipedia has  an article on 3 of those 4 topics.  Did you try reading those articles to see what you can learn?

Comment: different database providers interpret the terms slight differently. Depends on the database server. yeah I read all those.